# Wordpress - Media Queries not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I've tested some RWD media queries on a front-end test site and I've just copied the code over to my style.css file but they don't seem to want to work.I'm using the html5blank theme as a parent. This is what I have in my header.php -

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

        <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/style.css" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:100,200,400,700,700i,800,800i' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <script>
        // conditionizr.com
        // configure environment tests
        conditionizr.config({
            assets: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>',
            tests: {}
        });
        </script>

    </head>
```

I believe this is all as it should be. In my style.css I have this -

```
/*
 Theme Name:   HTML5 Blank Child Theme
 Description:  A child theme of the HTML5 Blank WordPress theme
 Author:       Mike Whitehead
 Template:     html5blank
 Version:      1.0.0
*/

/* ALL STYLES BELOW */
```

I have my media queries BELOW my bespoke styles but ABOVE my skeleton grid code -

```
/* RWD HERE */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  /* SOME CODE HERE */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 

  /* SOME CODE HERE */
}

/*
* Skeleton V2.0.4
* Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/29/2014
*/


/* Table of contents
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
- Grid
- Base Styles
- Typography
- Links
- Buttons
- Forms
- Lists
- Code
- Tables
- Spacing
- Utilities
- Clearing
- Media Queries
*/
```

Does my RWD media queries have to go at the absolute bottom of the style.css file? Is there something else I'm missing? Does it need to be indented?

Comment: yes. you media queries should go to at the bootom.

Comment: @vel That hasn't worked.

Comment: can you share me loading css list ?.

Comment: @vel What do you mean?

Comment: or did you try with `@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  /* SOME CODE HERE */
}`?

Comment: I mean which css files is loading first?

Comment: @vel Sorry for sounding dim but how can I tell that? I've copied my head code above.

Comment: @vel I just have the style.css file in my child theme - I have my bespoke files and skeleton.css copied into it. The parent theme has normalise.css

Comment: your header.php is fine.  it should load the /wp-content/them_name/style.css  make sure it does...

Comment: @AndyKillen It's loaded all the styles okay up to now. It must be something really simple but I just can't seem to spot it right now. Do I need a seperate file for responsive code? Is the skeleton.css code interfering?

Comment: tried my answer?

Comment: nope you do not need a separate css file for responsive.  Sometimes it can help to put your media queries at the end so that you don't overwrite them with the rest of your code.  i.e.

- mobile first  (all css)
- media query for tablet (if you need it)
- media query for desktop

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Hi, Peter, you helped me a couple of days ago on something. Any ideas what this may be? TIA:)

Answer (score 0):

you css should be like this.

```
        /*
        * Skeleton V2.0.4
        * Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
        * www.getskeleton.com
        * Free to use under the MIT license.
        * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
        * 12/29/2014
        */


        /* Table of contents
        ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
        - Grid
        - Base Styles
        - Typography
        - Links
        - Buttons
        - Forms
        - Lists
        - Code
        - Tables
        - Spacing
        - Utilities
        - Clearing
        - Media Queries
        */


        /* RWD HERE */
        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
          /* SOME CODE HERE */
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 

          /* SOME CODE HERE */
        }

        or

        @media (max-width: 1000px) {
          /* SOME CODE HERE */
        }

        @media (max-width: 480px) { 

          /* SOME CODE HERE */
        }
```

Media query should be bottom of `skeleton.css`.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are using a child theme and this header.php is returning the parent themes style.css

try using https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  to get the path to your actual CSS file.

your formatting is correct in your css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/style.css" />
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/style.css" />
```

Comment: I was using a child theme anyway and the styles were loading with my custom styles. Its just not loading my media queries at all.

Comment: then make sure as @vel suggests, that you load your media queries last.  double check your syntax against a good resource such as https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Are you suggesting that I need to change the link above or that its as it should be?

Comment: if it is loading the correct style.css for you now, ignore this as your doing ok.  it would work however if you did do it, but just not a necessity

Comment: This is quite frustrating.

Comment: I've just seen a post on a google search which suggests this may be a parent/child issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by creating a responsive.css stand-alone file and adding the following into my `header.php` file -

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/responsive.css" />
```